# Subversion with 32 bit server and 32/64 bit clients

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, 64-bit, 32-bit

Good morning; my google-fu seems to be lacking today.

I've just been upgraded to a Vista64 machine, and we only now have a 32 bit subversion server.

I assume there is no problem using 64bit tortoisesvn with the 32 bit server ?

Thanks.
Max.

(Edit)
Thank you all.

Comment: Another similar question you may ask yourself: Can I use a 64bit web browser (let's say IE7) with a 32bit web server?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There won't be a problem, they are basically independent since the protocol between them has done by another channel.

Also I've got he same setup and it works just fine.

Answer (score 2):

Correct, the architecture of server or client don't matter. SVN would have to be severly broken for it to matter, even.

Answer (score 1):

Similar situation to you, using a Vista x64 on development workstations and 2003 x32 for the reposetory server. Tortoise SVN x64 works fine.